# Integration of AWS Cognito with Android application without using AWS SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, androidx

I want to understand the best practice for end-user authentication in an Android application (self-hosted UI), the server is hosted on AWS.
I was looking at AWS Cognito for the custom authentication flow and that was working well when I am running the aws command using aws cli.
The same API if I am running through POSTMAN is giving the error:

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The server did not understand the operation that was requested.","type":"client"}
```

Later I found out that these AWS Cognito API is using SOAP protocol rather than REST. is it true?

I do not want to use AWS SDK for the following reason:

> 1. I am using Androidx for developing application.
> 2. The Application size is increasing by 10 - 15 MB.

Please help me out in having the REST API to interact with AWS Cognito for my custom authentication.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using `Lambda` for providing REST API?

Comment: yes @shafayathossain